# HibernateTemplate vs HibernateDaoSupport vs SessionFactory Injection

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have seen in lot of forums and still in confusion. We are starting a new project with Spring 3.1 & Hibernate 4 and need to decide which strategy to use for Hibernate with Spring:

1. Accessing Hibernate directly

   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
2. Using HibernateTemplate

   List bb = (List)hibernateTemplate.find("from Entity");
3. Using HibernateDAOSupport classes

   List bb =(List)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Entity");

Can you please help what should i use? I have read from [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/501712/Spring/HibernateTemplate-or-HibernateDaoSupport-or-Hibernate) and one another [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/479938/ORM/databases/Diff-between-Hinernate-Template-HibernateDAOSupport) which tell that from **Hibernate 3.x** onwards we should inject `SessionFactory` in our DAO Classes(using `@Repository`).

Can someone explain this in detail?

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Comment: Make sure that you really need Hibernate.  It's not necessary to work with databases.  Be sure that you know what the benefits and tradeoffs before you assume.

Comment: Hibernate is already finalized for new Project. But need to know the best strategy from above.

Comment: Great question, there's so much overlap between the different technologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring itself recommends not using HibernateTemplate anymore, in [the javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) of the class. You can [declare the session factory as a Spring bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-hibernate) directly, inject it as any other Spring bean in your own components, and use the native Hibernate API directly (using [sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-hibernate)).

Answer (score 4):

If you must use Hibernate, your best bet is to ignore Code Ranch (and SO) and follow the recommendation from Spring:

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

Answer (score 0):

Now SessionFactory is recomended for Hibernate 4 for open/close connection automatically. So no need to use HibernateTemplate class.